# PHP Score assigning

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a web page where people are able to post a single number between 0 and 10.

There is like a lotto single number generation once daily. I want my PHP script to check on the the posted numbers of all the users and assign a score of +1 or -1 to the relative winners (or losers).

The problem is that once I query the DB for the list of the winning users, I want to update their "score" field (in "users" table). I was thinking of a loop like this (pseudocode)

```
foreach winner{
    update score +1
}
```

but this would mean that if there are 100 winners, then there will be 100 queries. Is there a way to do some sort of batch inserting with one single query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the randomly picked number is also between 0 and 10? What's a relative winner (or loser)? Do they get -1 for guessing the wrong number and +1 for guessing the right number? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Sorry, no code to show. People get -1 for the wrong number, +1 for the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just assume we have a datatable named `posts` and `users`.
Obviously, `users` contain the data of the gambler (with a convenient `id` field and `points` for the number of points they have), and `posts` contain the `post_id` ID field for the row, `user_id`, which is the ID of the user and `value`, the posted number itself.

Now you only need to implement the following SQL queries into your script:

`UPDATE users INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id SET users.points = (users.points + 1)
WHERE posts.value = 0;`

Where `0` at the end is to be replaced with the randomly drawn number.

**What will this query do?** With the `INNER JOIN` construct, it will create a *link* between the two tables. Automatically, if `posts.value` matches our number, it will *link* `posts.user_id` to `users.id`, knowing which user has to get his/her `points` modified. If someone gambled `0`, and his ID (`posts.user_id`) is `8170`, the `points` field will update for the user having `user.id = 8170`.

If you alter the query to make it `(users.points - 1)` and `WHERE posts.value != 0`, you will get the non-winners having one point deducted. It can be tweaked as much as you want.

**Just be careful!** After each daily draw, the posts table needs to be truncated or archived.

Another option would be storing the timestamp (`time()` in PHP) of the user betting the number, and when executing, checking against the stored timestamp... whether it is in between the beginning and the end of the current day or not.

*Just a tip: you can use graphical database software (like Microsoft Access or LibreOffice Base) to have your `JOIN`s and such simulated on a graphical display. It makes modelling such questions **a lot** easier for beginners. If you don't want desktop-installed software, trying out an installation of `phpMyAdmin` is another solution too.*

---

***Edit:***

#### Non-relational databases

If you are to use non-relational databases, you will first need to fetch all the winner `ID`s with:

```
SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE value=0;
```

This will give you a result of multiple rows. Now, you will need to go through this result, one-by-one, and executing the following query:

```
UPDATE users SET points=(users.points + 1) WHERE id=1;
```

(`0` is the drawn winning number, `1` is the concurrent `id` of the user to update.)

Without using the relation capabilities of MySQL, but using a MySQL database, the script would look like this:

```
<?php
$number = 0; // This is the winning number we have drawn

$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE number=" .$number);

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    $curpoints_result = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM users WHERE user_id=" .$row['user_id']);
    $current_points = mysql_fetch_assoc($curpoints_results);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=" .($current_points['points'] + 1). " WHERE user_id=" .$row['user_id']);
}
?>
```

The `while` construct make this loop to run until every row of the result (list of winners) is updated.

*Oh and: I **know** MySQL is a **relational** database, but it is just what it is: an **example**.*

Comment: why do they need to be archived? so that it's not risky that the same winner is taken more than once?

Comment: also, is this possible on non-relational databases? how would the query look like? thank you :)

Comment: @enrico #1: It needs to be archived because if the same number is drawn on day 3 and day 8 (examples), then, when giving scores for the day 8 winners, the day 3 winners will get another point too.

Comment: @enrico For the second comment, you will need to split the query into one. First, fetch a list of all winners. Then, do the point append part on all the winners. (I have updated the answer to include this too.)

Comment: that's what i was thinking as well but, isn't having queries inside a loop a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how the numbers were stored. If there is a huge number of people posting, a good option is to use a database to store their numbers.

You can have for example a table called `lotto` with three fields: `posted_number`, `score` and `email`. Create an (non-unique!) index on the `posted_number` field.

```
create table lotto (posted_number integer(1) unsigned, score integer, email varchar(255), index(posted_number));
```

To update their score you can execute two queries:

```
update lotto set score = score+1 where posted_number = <randomly drawn number here>
update lotto set score = score-1 where posted_number = <randomly drawn number here>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are using a database, with sql, and suggest that would probably want to do something like

```
UPDATE `table` SET `score`=`score`+1 WHERE `number`=3;
```

and the corresponding -1 for losers (strange, can't see a reason to -1 them).

Without more details though, I can't be of further help.